# Check if all the images in the page are loaded

Tags: javascript

**The goal**: check if all images in the page are loaded. If yes, call to a function, if not, again to check if all images are loaded.

**My try**:

```
let checkImages = new Promise(resolve => { resolve(areCompleted()); });

function areCompleted() {
  let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  images = Array.from(images);

  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (!images[i].complete) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

If all images are completed, it resolves the promise with true, if not, false.

```
checkImages.then(completed => {
  if (completed) {
    completedFunction();
  } else {
    // Check again
  }
});
```

If the response is true, call a function, if not... *I don't know how to do the same check again*, but I want to do that checking until the response is true.

Comment: This seems like a bizarre use of promises. Normally you would resolve it only when all the images had loaded.

Comment: Do you just want an event to trigger when all the images are loaded, or do you *need* to use a promise?

Comment: @Archer I want to use a Promise because if I do the checking with a `while` loop I can block the script. I don't know if there are another methods.

Comment: That's why I ask the question - you're not actually looking for a promise, but that's what the question is about.  What you want is a way to trigger some code when all the images are loaded.  There are much simpler ways to do that that have been around a lot longer than promises.

Comment: @Archer if I want to do this check I can only think in `async`. I've tried it with `while`but in 3G network it blocks the script. In `async` I only know two methods: `Promise` and `async / await` functions.

Comment: Images trigger an event when they complete loading.  You don't need to keep checking over and over.  I'll write you some code.

Comment: @Archer I only know the `onload` method and it requires to attach the `src` to the `img` element after because if the image is loaded before listen the event, I will never know if the image is loaded.

Comment: It requires a mixture of checking the `complete` attribute and adding a load event handler.  See below.

Comment: A promise is not a function, you cannot call it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This function will check for already loaded images and attach an event listener to all the others so that it can tell when every image in a given container is loaded...

```js
function onImagesLoaded(container, event) {
    var images = container.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var loaded = images.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        if (images[i].complete) {
            loaded--;
        }
        else {
            images[i].addEventListener("load", function() {
                loaded--;
                if (loaded == 0) {
                    event();
                }
            });
        }
        if (loaded == 0) {
            event();
        }
    }
}

var container = document.getElementById("container");

onImagesLoaded(container, function() {
    alert("All the images have loaded");
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/C1SdoDActSv8tPONx_OjwEobUjw=/0x0:1004x753/1200x800/filters:focal(0x0:1004x753)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/49523369/20150428-cloud-computing.0.jpg" />
  <img src="https://images.techhive.com/images/article/2016/08/clouds-100678070-primary.idge.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.quali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/101-HEADER-IMAGE.jpg" />
  <img src="https://cdn.computerworlduk.com/cmsdata/features/3641280/cloud_istock_malerapaso_thumb800.jpg" />
</div>
```

This will still work if all the images have already loaded, due to being cached, or if there are no images in the container.

If you want to check all images in a page, simply change the container selector to the body instead...

```
var container = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
```

Comment: This is a valid solution, but, what happens if the image is loaded while the JS engine is adding the event listener? (In that precise milliseconds)

Comment: It won't - one has to happen before the other.

Comment: But images download it's not performed asynchronously by the browsers?

Comment: It's very unlikely to ever happen, but if the image is loaded at the precise moment that the event handler is added to the image then the next thing that would happen would be that JS is notified of the image load.  While the image loading is asynchronous, JS is not.  The image state can't change *during* that code.  Only before or after.

Comment: This is a solid solution, but referencing an outer-scoped variable in a loop may be confusing. What can be done to avoid this?

Comment: I think this will fail if an image src is invalid, the eventlistener should listen to the `error`-event aswell as the load even

Answer (score 0):

The code in the accepted answer is a great little ditty -- just one thing to add -- if there are zero images on the page, the event doesn't get called because the check for 0 is inside the loop.  So I would recommend this small change:

```
function onImagesLoaded(container, event) {
    var images = container.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var loaded = images.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        if (images[i].complete) {
            loaded--;
        }
        else {
            images[i].addEventListener("load", function() {
                loaded--;
                if (loaded <= 0) {
                    event();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    if (loaded <= 0) {
        event();
    }
}
```